# Stack elements of div vertically one below the other

Tags: html, css

I want the divs inside content_container to be stacked vertically below each other and not overlap. Please help.

My HTML code:

```
<div id=content_container>
    <div id=sub_nav>
    </div>
    <div id=content>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
#content_container{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#sub_nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#content{
    width: 100%;
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/28184.jpg
```

Comment: hmmm not sure what you're ultimately trying to achieve but removing position: fixed from #sub_nav will allow them to stack properly. Also, why are you floating left the #content_container?

Comment: @bl0cklevel I want #sub_nav and #content to be under each other but they display with #suub_nav overlapping #content. I don't want to remove position:fixed because I want #sub_nav to stay on the top of the page while scrolling. #content_container is floated left because I am stacking horizontally with another div

Comment: @MihirK98 Have a look at my answer it solves the problem of placing sub_nav at the top by using position sticky and flexbox!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTML

```
<div id=content_container>
    <div id=sub_nav>
    </div>
    <div id=content>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#content_container{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#sub_nav{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
}

#content{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Also, refer to https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for full flexbox reference.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the "position: fixed;" for the #sub_nav div. 
Remove that and they should stack one on top of the other.

Comment: But what if I want it to be fixed to the top of the page? Is there no way to do it?

Comment: Try experimenting with the heights of the divs placing background colors so you can easily see where they fit inside the #content_container div.

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easily to use flex boxes:

```css
#content_container {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

#sub_nav {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id=content_container>
    <div id=sub_nav>
    </div>
    <div id=content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```css
#content_container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#sub_nav{
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#content{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id=content_container>
    <div id=sub_nav>
    </div>
    <div id=content>
    </div>
  </div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to do with flex boxes.

```css
#content_container {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

#sub_nav {
  background: white;
  width: 100px;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id=content_container>
    <div id=sub_nav>
    </div>
    <div id=content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` takes the element out of the flow and make it fixed to the viewport. which leads the next element to overlap.

so you need to let fixed element `sub_nav` show on top. and `content` would show by giving it padding on top or move the top start point with relative

```
element{
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

[image]

**Example**

```css
#content_container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#sub_nav {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#content {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id=content_container>
  <div id=sub_nav>sub_nav
  </div>
  <div id=content>content
  </div>
</div>
```